# Найти и "забрать" адрес страницы из уже имеющегося текста

Tags: jsoup, регулярные-выражения, java, android

Помогите найти и "забрать" адрес страницы из уже имеющегося текста.

Есть такой текст :

```
<dt class="png" title="Ясно" style="background-image: url(http://st8.gisstatic.ru/static/images/icons/new/n.moon.png)">
```

Помогите забрать саму ссылку, а именно :

```
http://st8.gisstatic.ru/static/images/icons/new/n.moon.png
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Делал так:

```
public static StringBuffer links = new StringBuffer();
public static Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\b(http)://[-a-zA-Z0-9+&@#/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-a-zA-Z0-9+&@#/%=~_|]");

public static void searchLinks(String text) {
    String groupStr = "";
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(text);

    if (matcher.find()) {
        for (int i = 0; i < matcher.groupCount(); i++) {
            groupStr = matcher.group(i);
            links.append(groupStr);
            links.append("\n");
        }

        String subString = text.subSequence(text.indexOf(groupStr) + groupStr.length(), text.length()).toString();
        searchLinks(subString);
    }
}
```